# How to locate the modal div element within an iframe using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, iframe, css-selectors

I'm trying to get the `<div>` element within an iframe, but not able to find it.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options) driver.get("https://meuvaptvupt.com.br/pagina/agendamento")
try:
    time.sleep(5)
    modal = driver.find_element(by=By.ID, value="seleciona-cidade")
    print(modal) except NoSuchElementException:
    print("can't find it!!!") except:
    print("another error")
driver.quit()
```

The page doesn't show the element that I want. Some tips on how to do it?

What I want to see is a modal element, with the id `seleciona-cidade`, from the URL https://meuvaptvupt.com.br/pagina/agendamento

Comment: [You can use see this question learn different ways of formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element with *ID* as *`seleciona-cidade`* is the [Modal Overlay](https://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp)

[image: seleciona-cidade]

---

### Solution

If your usecase is to click or send a character sequence within the *query* field, the desired element is within an [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607451/7429447) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

  - Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

    ```
    driver.get("https://meuvaptvupt.com.br/pagina/agendamento")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a#accept-cookie"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe#iframe-agendamento")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.au-target +input[placeholder='Busque e selecione a cidade desejada']"))).click()
    ```
  - Using *XPATH*:

    ```
    driver.get("https://meuvaptvupt.com.br/pagina/agendamento")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@id='accept-cookie']"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@id='iframe-agendamento']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='au-target' ]//following::input[@placeholder='Busque e selecione a cidade desejada']"))).click()
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: agendamento]

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)